# Boot up into Chromium Web Page for a touchscreen

Tags: boot, chromium

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian OS
I would like the GUI to boot directly to a chromium web page in full screen.
All the tutorials i have read seem to be out of date.
I have created the autostart files in the /LXDE-pi folder and the alternative etc/xdg .... etc
Nothing happens no browser no error just boots to desktop.
Any pointers would be greatly received.
Thanks

Comment: Whatever you found, try searching for Kiosk mode. In past i used one on Dakboard. Try looking there. Also this looks like newest tutorial : https://www.raspberrypi.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-raspberry-pi-in-kiosk-mode/

Comment: Hi, it's really simple just go to the wayfire.ini file in your user folder and put [autostart] then chromium-browser --fullsceeen.